# Woocommerce - How to add custom amount for product into cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I am looking for some help in regards to adding a custom price for a product. The website I am building is for a charity hence there is no set price for the product and its a case of how much the user would like to donate.

My site is being built in Wordpress version 4.9.6 and I am using Woocommerce in order to have the e-commerce functions, unfortunately this is on my localhost at present but I have found an example of a similar site that has the same function.

https://www.liarelieftrust.org/product/sudan-food-pack/

Under Choose your Donation amount dropdown there is a section for Other amount.

This is what I am looking to add in my backend but unsure on how I could achieve the same thing.

Would appreciate if somebody could advise on how I can add this onto my site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can be done without any code need, using variable products… You will have to set 2 attributes before: one for the funds and the other for the prices… Then once those attributes created, you will be able to set them in a variable product… refer to official documentation for [variable products in Woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/)

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, I have managed to setup the attributes, but it's the dropdown with the other amount that pops up that I can't work out how to do.

Comment: Thank you Loic for all your advice. Unfortunately will need custom code or a plugin in order to achieve this.

Comment: Make some search before… If you don't find a plugin that can match, try to find some related code that you will add in your question, to get some chances to get helped on StackOverFlow. Don't forget to set a name for your User.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-open-pricing-name-your-price-for-woocommerce/#installation found this link which looks useful..

Comment: You need to find something that works with variable products in your case, as you have many funds. If not this plugin can be convenient for simple produvcts.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to find an extension that will do this on variable products. Woocommerce Name Your Price...